# react application publish with IIs and react-router dosnt work

Tags: reactjs, iis, publish

ive published a react app on windows server with IIS but when i try to refresh pages with f5 in my app this error came out :
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
some one please help me!!!

ive tried many ways but the problem didnt solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you have to install URL Rewrite module. After successful installation, you need to create the following rules under your React application site that will rewrite all non-API requests to the root URL ("/") where the React application's routes will handle them.

```
<rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api/(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

Reference link: https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied